# Как вытащить параметры с JSP страницы?

Tags: java, spring, mvc

Есть JSP страница, на которой меняется какой-то текст, как можно изменения текста передавать на контроллер? 
То есть при нажатии на кнопку "отправить" у нас передавались поля, которые мы хотим (допустим чекбокс, текстбокс и текст, который брался из БД)

Comment: Используйте тег <form>: http://htmlbook.ru/html/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После нажатия на кнопку "отправить" вы получите HTML-request. В таком случае ваш вопрос лучше переформулировать: как передать параметры HTML-request на контроллер. Обычно в таких случаях используют аннотацию ***@RequestParam***
Более подробно можете рассмотреть эту проблему [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060839/spring-mvc-and-checkboxes)